# iOS 7 Navigation bar wrong content

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, landscape

I have a problem with navigation bar in iOS 7. iOS 8 and iOS 9 work fine. I will try to explain, I cannot show screenshots.

I have MainViewController. That primary controller is embedded in Navigation Controller. In MainViewController's navigation bar there is logo in the middle, left is menu icon (classic drawer) and right button item is settings.

From menu controller, you can choose to show a list of records. Let's call that list RecordsViewController. RecordsViewController  has back button, title and filter button in navigation bar. Each record has a picture. When you click on a record, new PictureViewController is shown.

In that view controller you can swipe right/left to previous/next picture. RecordsViewController and PictureViewController work in portrait and landscape modes.

I will now type step by step to create issue:

1. when you go to RecordsViewController, you choose a record, click on it and it goes to PictureViewController.
2. Scroll some pictures and put PictureViewController in landscape mode.
3. When you hit back on PictureViewController, RecordsViewController has now wrong navigation bar loaded, it loads navigation bar from MainViewController.
4. When you put it after that in portrait mode it switches to navigation bar that should have been.
5. If you put RecordsViewController in landscape, choose record to see picture, PictureViewController will be in landscape mode.
6. If you click back now, everything is ok. This problem only occurs in iOS 7. Any ideas.? I've tried to set in viewWillAppear navigation bar every time, it does not work.

**EDIT:** I am using navigation controller navigation bar and items. So this is init navigation bar method that is called in `viewWillAppear`:

```
- (void) initNavBar {
self.title = @"Records";

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.tintColor = PRIMARY_BACKGROUND_COLOR;

self.navigationItem.titleView = nil;

self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = SECONDARY_TEXT_COLOR;

[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"ProximaNova-Light" size:17],
                                                                  NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor blackColor]}];

[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc] init] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setShadowImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];
}
```

Exactly the same method is in my MainViewController with different stuff for MainViewController. When I turn to portrait mode, from landscape, right content is shown. I am not having outlet for navigation bar. I am using navigation controller's navigation bar directly.

Comment: you need to show some code!!! When it comes to navighation bar, you need to take care of presenting it!!! Deallocate the unused nav bars in the viewWillDisappear, and load the new nav bars in view will appear!!

Comment: can't show code, can't show screenshots .... can't get help.

Comment: I've not written that I cannot show code. I was trying to resolve it, I am not refreshing this every two seconds.